# Running all testcases at once in DUnitX

Tags: delphi, dunitx

I have a test with several test cases, ex:

```
    [Test]
    [TestCase('Case1', '1')]
    [TestCase('Case2', '2')]
    [TestCase('Case3', '3')]
    procedure RunTest(const aParam: integer);
```

I can run each test case separately including test case name in parameter, like *-rMyUnit.TMyTestClass.RunTest.Case1*

My question is: how to run all test cases at once, something like *-rMyUnit.TMyTestClass.RunTest.**

I have tried without test case name, but no luck, it cannot find the test at all.

Comment: I don't get your problem, just call the testrunner? something like GUITestRunner.RunRegisteredTests;

Comment: I don't need to run all the tests (I have hundreds). I'm testing a new feature with my new RunTest method and I want to run its 3 test cases **only** at once (without specifying each one separately in parameter).

Answer (score 1):

It is **not possible** according to the code of DUnitX 2015.

A workaround is to give the **same test case's name** for all a of one test.

```
unit rMyUnit;

interface

type

  [TestFixture]
  TMyTestClass = class
  public
    [Test]
    [TestCase('CaseX', '1')]
    [TestCase('CaseX', '2')]
    [TestCase('CaseX', '3')]
    procedure RunTest(const aParam: integer);
  end;
```

To run these 3 test cases, run with the parameter :

> -run:rMyUnit.TMyTestClass.RunTest.CaseX